# Can you compare values across probes in a multi-CPU safe way in DTrace?

Tags: macos, dtrace

I'm trying to write a DTrace script which does the following:

1. Whenever a new thread is started, increment a count.
2. Whenever one of these threads exits, decrement the count, and exit the script if the count is now zero.

I have something like this:

```
BEGIN {
  threads_alive = 0;
}

proc:::lwp-start /execname == $$1/ {
  self->started = timestamp;
  threads_alive += 1;
}

proc:::lwp-exit /self->started/ {
  threads_alive -= 1;
  if (threads_alive == 0) {
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, because `threads_alive` is a scalar variable and thus it is not multi-cpu safe. As a result, multiple threads will overwrite each other's changes to the variable.

I have also tried using an aggregate variable instead:

```
@thread_count = sum(1)
//or
@threads_entered = count();
@threads_exitted = count();
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found syntax to be able to do something like `@thread_count == 0` or `@threads_started == @threads_stopped`.

Comment: DTrace doesn't have facilities for doing the kind of thread-safe data sharing that you are proposing here. Can you provide a little more context about what you're trying to do? Would `proc:exit/execname == $$1/{ exit(0) }` work? Does the `-c` or `-p` option already do what you want?

Comment: @ahl Thanks, that makes sense. I am hoping to have dtrace start before the process starts so that it can capture the lwp-start probe for that process (which doesn't seem to happen when I am using `-c`, at least on MacOS). Then I start the process, and observe until it ends, at which point I would like dtrace to exit. It seems like proc:::exit works, so long as I don't run the process multiple times (which I don't plan to). If you'd like, write up that as an answer and I'll accept, or I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTrace doesn't have facilities for doing the kind of thread-safe data sharing you're proposing, but you have a few options depending on precisely what you're trying to do.

If the executable name is unique, you can use the `proc:::start` and `proc:::exit` probes for the start of the first thread and the exit of the last thread respectively:

```
proc:::start
/execname == $$1/
{
        my_pid = pid;
}

proc:::exit
/pid == my_pid/
{
        exit(0);
}
```

If you're using the `-c` option to `dtrace`, the `BEGIN` probe fires very shortly after the corresponding `proc:::start`. Internally, `dtrace -c` starts the specified forks the specified command and then starts tracing at one of four points: `exec` (before the first instruction of the new program), `preinit` (after ld has loaded all libraries), `postinit` (after each library's `_init` has run), or `main` (right before the first instruction of the program's `main` function, though this is not supported in macOS).

If you use `dtrace -x evaltime=exec -c <program>` `BEGIN` will fire right before the first instruction of the program executes:

```
# dtrace -xevaltime=exec -c /usr/bin/true -n 'BEGIN{ts = timestamp}' -n 'pid$target:::entry{printf("%dus", (timestamp - ts)/1000); exit(0); }'
dtrace: description 'BEGIN' matched 1 probe
dtrace: description 'pid$target:::entry' matched 1767 probes
dtrace: pid 1848 has exited
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
 10  16757                _dyld_start:entry 285us
```

The 285us is due to the time it takes `dtrace` to resume the process via `/proc` or `ptrace(2)` on macOS. Rather than `proc:::start` or `proc:::lwp-start` you may be able to use `BEGIN`, `pid$target::_dyld_start:entry`, or `pid$target::main:entry`.